# How to make a field with urls of model-1 instances that are related to model-2 instance inside the serializer of model-2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the model **Dish** that has the `ForeignKey` relationship with the model **DishesType**:

```
class DishesType(models.Model):
    # some fields ...


class Dish(models.Model):
    # some fields ...
    type_of_food = models.ForeignKey(DishesType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I perform the `retrieve` method to get single **DishesType** model instance I want also to display the urls of all **Dish** model instances that are related to current **DishesType** instance.

For example **DishesType** instance `Pizza` has 3 related **Dish** instances: `Meet Pizza`, `Hawaiian Pizza` and `Cheese Pizza`. So when I retrieve page `site.com/dishes-types/pizza` I want to have the next serialization:

```
{
    "name": "Pizza",
    "dishes_type_url": "site.com/dishes-types/pizza/",
    ...
    "dishes": {
        "Meet Pizza": "site.com/dishes/meet-pizza/",
        "Hawaiian Pizza": "site.com/dishes/hawaiian-pizza/",
        "Cheese Pizza": "locasite.comlhost/dishes/cheese-pizza/"
    }
},
```

I've tried to do it by the next approach(replaced meta-classes):

```
class DishSerializer(ValidateNameMixin, HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """The serializer of the 'Dish' model"""
    dish_url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="dish-detail", lookup_field="name")


class SingleDishesTypeSerializer(ValidateNameMixin, HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """The serializer of the 'DishesType' model"""
    dishes_type_url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="dishes_type-detail", lookup_field="name")
    dishes = SerializerMethodField(source="get_dishes")

    @staticmethod
    def get_dishes(dish_type):
        all_current_dishes_type_dishes = Dish.objects.filter(type_of_food=dish_type)
        # Here I'm getting the error displayed below
        serializer = DishSerializer(all_current_dishes_type_dishes, many=True)

        ...

        return some_data
```

But of course I'm getting the next error:

```
'HyperlinkedIdentityField' requires the request in the serializer context. Add 'context={'request': request}' when instantiating the serializer.
```

Obviously I can't get access to the `request` object from serializer, so what should I do to make my idea completed?

Comment: Where did you use `request`? You're not showing all the code.

Comment: @DavidLu what code do you also need ? `request` object, that is passed to views, can't be accessed inside serializer's method if I not pass it directly from views, and this is one of the ways to solve my issue, but I think this approach is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need pass `request` when you create the `DishSerializer` instance.

```
class SingleDishesTypeSerializer(ValidateNameMixin, HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_dishes(dish_type):
        ...
        serializer = DishSerializer(all_current_dishes_type_dishes, context={'request': self.context['request']}, many=True)
```

Comment: Seriously ? There is no difference what function argument name you set..